# T. Lyons Criterion 

Tags: pr.probability, random-graphs

Hello all,

I want to prove that any flow on the following tree must have an infinite energy.

The structure of the graph is (taken from R.Lyons and Y.Peres book)

"We’ll construct a tree $T$ embedded in the upper half plane with o at the origin. We’ll have $|T_n| = 2^n$, but we’ll connect them in a funny way. List $T_n$ in clockwise order as $(x^n_1
, . . . , x^n_{2^n})$. Let $x^n_k$ have $1$ child if $k \leq  2^{n−1}$ and $3$ children otherwise."

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, this tree is recurrent, so of course any flow must have infinite energy...

Comment: Ori, i want to prove that this tree is recurrent using the fact that any flow must have...

Lee, you right. First, it should be $|T_n| = 2^n$. It means that the cardinality of the $n$th level of the tree is equal to $2^n$ ($2^n$ vertices). 

Flow is an anti-symmetric function for which the divergence is not zero at the root and zero elsewhere. The energy is, of course, defined by the inner product on $L^2(E)$ (edges).

Comment: Have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102283/simple-random-walk-on-the-3-1-tree-is-recurrent

Comment: Thank you! The truth is that I already saw this thread, but again, I wish to prove the recurrences property directly by showing that any flow must have infinite energy. 

Comment: StarDust: I understood that, should've added a smiley ;-)

To the point, the 3-1 tree "ends" in countably many infinite paths. If the flow assigns a positive quantity to any of these paths it yields infinite energy.

Comment: Should that be $k \le 2^{n-1}$ instead of $k \le 2n-1$? Anyway, I don't understand what you need more than what I proved for the other question. The same proof shows there is no flow with finite energy.